# Basic OpenCL Mutex Implementation (Currently Hanging)

Tags: opencl, mutex

I am trying to write a mutex for OpenCL.  The idea is for every single individual work item to be able to proceed atomically.  Currently, I believe the problem may be that thread warps are unable to proceed when one thread in a warp gets the lock.

My current simple kernel below, for summing numbers.  "numbers" is an array of floats as input.  "sum" is a one element array for the result, and "semaphore" is a one element array for holding the semaphore.  I based it heavily off the example [here](http://www.cmsoft.com.br/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=113&Itemid=168).

```
void acquire(__global int* semaphore) {
    int occupied;
    do {
        occupied = atom_xchg(semaphore, 1);
    } while (occupied>0);
}
void release(__global int* semaphore) {
    atom_xchg(semaphore, 0); //the previous value, which is returned, is ignored
}
__kernel void test_kernel(__global float* numbers, __global float* sum, __global int* semaphore) {
    int i = get_global_id(0);
    acquire(semaphore);
    *sum += numbers[i];
    release(semaphore);
}
```

I am calling the kernel effectively like:

```
int numof_dimensions = 1;
size_t offset_global[1] = {0};
size_t size_global[1] = {4000}; //the length of the numbers array
size_t* size_local = NULL;
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, numof_dimensions,offset_global,size_global,size_local, 0,NULL, NULL);
```

As above, when running, the graphics card hangs, and the driver restarts itself.  How can I fix it so that it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this might seem obvious in retrospect, but it's not unless you thought of it.

Basically, the GPU's prediction of the ideal local group size (size of a thread warp) is greater than 1, and so thread warps lock up.  To fix it, you just need to specify it to be 1 (i.e. "size_t size_local[1] = {1};").  Doing this produces a correct result.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is not possible because of the GPU execution model, where all threads on a "processor" share the instruction pointer, even in branches. Here is a post that explains the problem in detail: http://vansa.ic.cz/author/admin/.

BTW, the example code that you found has the exact same problem and would never work.

Comment: I am aware of the way the GPU works.  However, using a local size of one (as the example code does) works perfectly.  I take this as evidence that doing so gives each thread warp exactly one thread (or rather, only one thread's execution is saved).  Thread warps cannot lock up, since there's only one thread running in each one!  The cited link gives another interesting workaround, though I think it ultimately does the same thing in a less portable way.